# I'm unclear on how to use the + selector in SCSS code

Tags: sass, css-selectors

I was running through a project today and wanted to use the + selector to limit the scope of my style parameters. I ran into an interesting problem though. Something like this was causing issues/Excedrin:

```
li {
    selector: 10px;
    selector: 12%;
    &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        &+a:after {
            content: "";
            fancyborderstuff: stuff;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't hold me to that as a functional example. The important part is that I intended to get an ELEMENT+ELEMENT and instead got NOTHING/ZERO. Poof, may as well have typed "derp".

So, what is the proper way to use the + selector when nesting in SCSS?

Comment: "The important part is that I intended to get an ELEMENT+ELEMENT and instead got NOTHING/ZERO." So does it just up and vanish from the generated CSS?

Comment: Yeah, it was as though nothing at all happened. I wish I'd saved the code in that state for an example. I basically ended up overwriting the pseudo-selector further down the nav tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no chance how to get `li + a` in your code.

ULs can have only LI children, so you have these options:

```
& + li {}   /* next LI */
& a {}      /* A in current LI, shorter just A, without & */
& + li a {} /* A in next LI */
```

Comment: That was probably the issue then, I was doing something CSS didn't like. I was trying to grab only a tags on an LI in a hovered state, but not grab them further than the first nav tier. It was pretty convoluted. Appreciate the clarification on the selector rule.

Comment: I would be surprised if the SCSS compiler actually went and deleted arbitrary rulesets based on HTML validation rules though @Imperative - but the way you described it sounds a lot like that's exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @BoltClock I wish I'd checked. It may have written the rule through as the format passed validation, but CSS simply ignored it because I was using + from a pseudo-selector to an anchor.